# Apache Mod Rewrite: RewriteRule with L argument. What's wrong?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm developing a php application and I have a little issue with Apache and Mod Rewrite. Anyone knows what's wrong here?:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^css\/css\.css css/css.php [L]
RewriteRule ^js\/js\.js js/js.php [L]
RewriteRule !^img\/.* index.php
```

When I put http://localhost/css/css.css appears index.php, maybe I'm missing something...
Why when the url matchs with the first rule apache doesn't stop the rewriting process?

> 'last|L' (last rule)
>
> Stop the rewriting process here and
>   don't apply any more rewriting rules.
>   This corresponds to the Perl last
>   command or the break command from the
>   C language. Use this flag to prevent
>   the currently rewritten URL from being
>   rewritten further by following rules.
>   For example, use it to rewrite the
>   root-path URL ('/') to a real one,
>   e.g., '/e/www/'.

I have readed forums and docs since 3 hours and I still have the same problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these rules being put in .htaccess or in your main apache config (often http.conf)?  That will change the behavior of mod_rewrite.

Comment: @Alan, true, but for the peanut gallery, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteRule ^css\/css\.css css/css.php [L]
RewriteRule ^css\/(.*)$ css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js\/js\.js js/js.php [L]
RewriteRule ^js\/(.*)$ js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=$1
```

It works fine, but I don't know why it's necessary

```
RewriteRule ^css\/(.*)$ css/$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^js\/(.*)$ js/$1 [L]
```

I hope it hepls anyone.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Centauro12, the problem is, that the [L] flag in fact stops propagation through the following rules, **but then** (if you are in an .htaccess file) the URL mapping **starts over again**. That means, **all** your rules will then be processed a second time. See the [Apache Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html#flag_l) for the details.

Therefore you need to explicitly disable rewriting for your rewritten php scripts:

```
RewriteRule ^css/css.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^js/js.php - [L]
```

or more compact (although perhaps not what you want):

```
# don't rewrite anything that really exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
RewriteRule ^/css/css\.css css/css.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/js/js\.js js/js.php [L]
RewriteRule ! /^img/.* index.php
```

ie. if you `^`-anchor the [pattern](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#patterns) to the beginning of the string, start it with a `/`. patterns are matched against [URL-paths](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax), which start with `/`.

**EDIT**

above is valid for server config, virtual host, and directory [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) only. if the context is .htaccess, the per-directory prefix including the first slash is stripped before the rule is matched (and prepended afterwards), so no need for `^/` here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say than my RewriteBase is:
RewriteBase /mysite/

It isn't work for me.

Thanks

Comment: Most examples over at Apache omit the slash, and I never had problems with matching `^payload` compared to `^/payload`.

Comment: ...that is, in a .htaccess context.

Comment: ... which he hadn't said when i wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set your rewrite base to "/" before starting your expression with "^css..."

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: or just put a / following the ^ char in both the css and js rules.

Comment: Ok, my RewriteBase is /mysite/

RewriteRule !^img\/.* index.php
works fine, but the css and js rules doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Cheeso: The leading `/` is only needed if mod\_rewrite is used in the server or virtual host configuration.