# mod_rewrite loops even with L flag

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a problem with rewriting a URL to a fastcgi dispatcher. If I leave only:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I expected `L` (last rule) to cause only a single rewrite. Instead, it keeps prepending `dispatch.fcgi` until apache reports an error.

I know it can be fixed with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But what is the reason for multiple rewrites? Does `L` do something else than I think it does?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but to others searching for the **REAL answer**, here it is:

The `[L]` flag **DOES** work in `.htaccess` files. It tells the `rewrite module` to skip all of the following rules in that particular `.htaccess` file. It does its job, Apache rewrites the url and exits the `.htaccess` file.

However, at the end of the `.htaccess` file **if the request url has been rewritten, the whole url matching process starts again with the new url**.

This is what happens above, `^(.*)$` will **always match** the current url, it causes an infinite loop, only the `maxredirect` rewrite option (10 by default) stops it.

**The `!-f` file attribute test** (as mentioned by the questioner) would **solve the problem**, since the url will match a real filename:

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L,QSA]

now, if we request `http://example.com/toappend`, `.htaccess` rewrites it to `dispatch.fcgi/toappend` and **no rewrite loop** will happen.

Comment: Why is it that if I do `rewriterule .* /index.php`, there is an infinite loop, yet if I do `rewriterule .* index.php` there is no loop?

Comment: Ok, I've found the ans and written it down linked here

Answer (score 5):

Hy , add this after `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

.. and it should work stoping loops .

Answer (score 1):

Apparently -- and I only read this here, I have no first hand knowledge -- the [L] directive does not work in .htaccess files, only if its in your .conf file.

See: [Hidden features of mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-modrewrite)

> within the .htaccess context, [L] will
>   not force mod_rewrite to stop. it will
>   continue to trigger internal

Comment: I guess that answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775877/ too - unfortunatley the real answer wasn't marked there...

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem, and it turns out that the best solution in Apache 2.3.9+ is to use **END** flag instead of **L** as it prevents mod_rewrite from looping over rules.