# Simulating MVC/CoC folder structure in php with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My project directory structure:

```
project_root/
|- src/
|  |- model/
|  |- view/
|  |- controller/
|  -- ...others
-- resources/
   |- css/
   |- js/
   -- images/
```

Ok, somewhere in `src` there is a file responsible for redirecting controllers, views and so on, let us say it is the `src/url_mapping.php`, it is prepared to solve any kind of url, such as `/{controller}/{action}/{id}?{query}`, there is no problem here, the big deal is I do not want the user realize this folder structure exists, I want to hide it from them and let the flow as simples as RoR and other based systems.

I want allow only `http://host/{css,js,images}/*` from `resources` without allowing `http://host/resources/*` itself, and `http://host/{controller}/{action}/{id}?{query}` to the `src/url_mapping.php` file denying direct access to `http://host/src`.

For now, the closest I managed is the following `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/resources/$1 !-f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/resources/$1 !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/resources/$1 !-l
    RewriteRule (?!^resources/|^src/url_mapping.php/)^(.*)$ src/url_mapping.php/$1 [L,PT]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/resources/$1 -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/resources/$1 -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/resources/$1 -l
    RewriteRule (?!^resources/)^(.*)$ /resources/$1 [L,PT]
</IfModule>
```

In that case my first intention was: If users tries to get `/resources` or `/src` folder it will be filtered by `src/url_mapping.php` as well, although I am trying several combinations with no success over and over again.

I noted `mod_rewrite` are in loop such a way I can not block `resources` directory as well as `src/url_mapping.php`, I am limited to `.htaccess` file with my hands tied, but if there is another way to do that I will accept the solution.

The last choice is do only one redirect and treating even files in `resources` by `src/url_mapping.php`, but it will kill the cache, I am avoiding reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Here the reason of my burden: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13446636/3122886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I realised apache is not so smart, so an acceptable solution I found was changing the directory tree to hide the non-resources content such a way apache cannot access.

Imagine the `DocumentRoot` is `/home/user/www`, so if you browse to `http://hostname/somefile` will point to `/home/user/www/somefile`, this way files in `/home/user/somedir/somefile` is not accessible by apache, but could be accessible by your PHP script if it has ownership/permission over that directory.

So, everything in `resources` I put on `/home/user/www` and the `src` was on `/home/user/private_html`, only my `url_mapping.php` stayed on `/home/user/www/index.php`, this way I can fool the user if I throw `404 Not Found` when direct accessing it.

The final tree:

```
project_root
|- private_html
|  |- model
|  |- view
|  |- controller
|  -- ...others
-- public_html
   |- css
   |- js
   |- images
   -- index.php
```

Where my `.htaccess` file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase / # Change it if there are a subdirectory

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my `index.php` is:

```
<?php

if (!array_key_exists('REDIRECT_URL', $_SERVER) && substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}

define('VALID_KERNEL', true);

require '../private_html/core/core.php';

$server = new Server();
$server->request(array_key_exists('PATH_INFO', $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : '/', $_REQUEST);

?>
```

This way it permits to access `index.php` only if it is the `DirectoryIndex`, I mean, `http://hostname/` is allowed but `http://hostname/index.php` is `404 Not Found` because this file should not exist, as well as `http://hostname/index.php/anything` and `http://hostname/index.php?anything`, although `http://hostname/anything` will redirect to `http://hostname/index.php/anything` but with `REDIRECT_URL` so it is allowed.