# Why does this rewrite rule give me this error?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite

```
http://localhost/messages/index.php?s=compose
```

to

```
http://localhost/messages/compose
```

but it gives me `Internal Server Error`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^messages/([^/]*)$ /messages/index.php?s=$1 [L]
```

I'm using a online site where you can generate rules so it should work, on the site I can make a rule to rewrite it to `http://localhost/compose.html` that works and gives me no error, but rewriting for `http://localhost/messages/compose` give me error.

Mod rewrite engine is on

Is it something to do with fact that messages is a folder/directory?

Comment: Look in the Apache error log for more details on what the error was. But most likely it is a redirect loop wherein `index.php` matches the same rule again and rewrites itself.  Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before `RewriteRule`.

Comment: You were right, that RewriteCond fixed it. thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite loops even with L flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127131/mod-rewrite-loops-even-with-l-flag)

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the dot in pattern.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^messages/([^/.]*)$ /messages/index.php?s=$1 [L]
```