# dot (.) in regex changes return of RewriteRule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My goal is to redirect from `domain.com/app/public/index.php?route=news/test/action` to `domain.com/news/test/action`.

I used the following regex:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/]*)$ app/public/index.php?route=$1 [NC]
```

This works when I call `domain.com/news/test`.

Now I want to also consider files to be routed so I include dots (.) in the regex like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/.]*)$ app/public/index.php?route=$1 [NC]
```

Now when I call `domain.com/news/test` the output of $1 is not `news/test` but `app/public/index.php`.

What happened?

Comment: Sorry, but you must have confused something in your test. `app/public/index.php` is _not_ part of the request string you _claim_ you used. It is impossible that it is captured. So most likely you ran into a rewriting loop.

Comment: I never heard of a rewriting loop. Is it possible that the rule rewrites itself?

Comment: A rule (obviously) can not "rewrite itself". But a simple google search for a "rewrite loop" would have helped you: the rewrite engine is started again after your rule matches and now the rule is applied a _second_ time to the _new_ url resulting from the first rewrite.

Comment: Look up the `L` flag in the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) - basically it means "after this rule has been applied, don't apply any more".

Comment: @megaflop this is not exactly true like I found out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13446636/1402958

Answer (score 0):

you used `/.` which means `/ or any symbol` . If you want to use dot, use `\.`

Comment: I tried `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/\.]*)$ app/public/index.php?route=$1 [NC]` but get the same result.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `.` just means `.` when inside a character class (`[.]`). It would be pretty pointless for it to retain the "any character" meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @arkascha I found the answer is a rewrite loop.

This code solved the problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/\.]*)$ app/public/index.php?route=$1 [NC]
```

Thanks!

---

EDIT: My solution seems to have a problem with existing files like CSS files. It also redirects those. I will update as soon as I have a better way doing this...