# Url rewriting HTML and CSS paths

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file in the root of my application:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This basically just convert paths such as `index/var=value/var2=values2/` into `index?url=index/var=value/var2=values2/` and in index.php they are elaborated to fetch `$controller` which is the name of the controller called (in this case `index`) and the `$get` which is the substitute for `$_GET`. (In this case it contains: `$get['var'] = 'value'` e `$get['var2'] = 'value2'`).

Notice: In the root file, where the .htacces file and the index.php are, we have also the `application/` folder (which contains controllers, views, and models), the `system/` folder which initialize the framework and the `public/` folder which should contains every image/javascript/css/video/audio file which can be accessed.

The .htaccess allows me to access directly every existing file both images and css. Which is great. The only problem that occurs is when the path to that image/javascript/css/audio/video file is inside the HTML or CSS files. So that when you call (*1) `<img src="public/img/image.jpg"/>` or when you call (*2) `background-image: url(public/img/image.jpg);` it just doesn't work.

That could be "solved" using absolute paths such as `http://dominio.com/public/img/image.jpg` but it is tricky when it comes to javascript files. And anyway is not a solution at all, but just a way to bypass the problem.

How could I make (*1) and (*2) work?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "it just doesn't work" ? do you get a 404 error or is it redirected to the index.php or... ?

Comment: @Fabrizio because if I call /public/img/image.jpg on http://dominio.com/index/var=value/var2=values2/ (URL rewriting) it looks for http://dominio.com/index/var=value/var2=values2/public/img/image.jpg which obliviously does not exists because the path is actually http://dominio.com/public/img/image.jpg

Comment: If you add a `/` at the beginning of the URL it always look for the root of the website, if you use `./` or `no /`, then it pulls from the current folder. `/public/file.css` called from `dominio.com/index/var=1` does pull `dominio.com/public/file.css`. `public/file.css` or `./public/file.css` will pull from the wrong folder.  BTW, you might want to add also `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php` to your `.htaccess`

Comment: also, look at this post for the `.htaccess`, seems like you might have a problem with the first `RewriteRule`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775877/apache-mod-rewrite-rewriterule-with-l-argument-whats-wrong

Comment: on a different note, please be careful because I can call your site with `/index/var=var1/?url=this_is_bad`

Comment: @Fabrizio This doesn't really harm... the first /index/ is considered to be the name of the controller and it is checked so that if you enter something like "./index" is ignored and every symbol except for _ is deleted. The second /var=var1/ is considered a 2 pieces segment where everything before = is the name of the variable and everything after is the value. If there's no = the segment is just ignored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this path?

```
/public/img/image.jpg
```

**EDIT/ADD**

didn't test this, but you can try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public        [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/other_folder  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/more_folders
    RewriteRule (.*) /project/$1
```

OR, have index.php process everything, and the very fist lines are a check to see if the called files exists based on the current path:

```
//untested code
$url = str_replace('..','',$_GET['url']);
if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$url)){
   //redirect to that file or serve it with PHP
   exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background-image: url(public/img/image.jpg);
```

will look in `public/img` path relative to the CSS file.

What you should probably be using is `../img/image.jpg`
or `/public/img/image.jpg`